# Como remover um item em uma posição de um array?

Tags: c#, array

Exemplo:

```
string[] x = {"3","2","1"};
```

quero tirar só o item `"2"` do array `x`, resultando em:

```
x = {"3","1"};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforme o vetor em um [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) e utilize o método [`RemoveAt(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string[] x = {"3","2","1"};
var lista = x.ToList(); // cria um objeto do tipo List<string> a partir do vetor
lista.RemoveAt(1); // remove o item na posição 1
x = lista.ToArray(); // recria o vetor a partir da lista
```

Se não sabe a posição do elemento a ser excluído, faça assim:

```
string[] x = {"3","2","1"};
int[] lista = x.ToList(); // cria o objeto do tipo List<string> a partir do vetor
lista.Remove("2"); // remove a primeira ocorrência do elemento que for equivalente a "2"
x = lista.ToArray()l // recria o vetor a partir da lista
```

Às vezes você pode analisar seu código e ver se há mesmo a necessidade de utilizar um array. Muitas vezes utilizar uma implementação de [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), como o [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), facilita bastante.

São muito específicas as vezes que há necessidade de usar um array. Se precisa adicionar e remover itens é conveniente utilizar um [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), por exemplo. Redimensionar arrays é algo custoso.

Vou deixar ["Arrays considered somewhat harmful"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/) do Eric Lippert como recomendação de leitura.